# Codeigniter HMVC Cron Job (CLI) Failing

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface

I am using HMVC with codeigntier and try to run a cron job.
I am using this for the cron:

```
php /home/onlblcm/dev.mytranslator.com/index.php mytranslator cron cronTranslations > aaa.txt 2>&1
```

When running this from cron job, in aaa.txt file I get

```
Set-Cookie: ci_session=e56ef3d7d05652937b3269852d8b36eaeebba9a2; expires=Wed, 05-Sep-2018 13:39:26 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Refresh:0;url=http/http/user/login
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

So it's super strange for me.
If I run the exact same command

```
php /home/onlblcm/dev.mytranslator.com/index.php mytranslator cron cronTranslations > aaa.txt 2>&1
```

From Putty (ssh) I get what I need. The file runs good. I get the desired output.
 So it's the exact same command, but with CRON it fails.

I checked to see in SSH, and I am using user onlblcm
 I checked the cron, and it's using the same user: onlblcm

So what can be the problem?

**EDIT1:**
 I added -f in front of the index.php and I now get the error output:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message:  ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time

Filename: Session/Session.php

Line Number: 284

```
<p>Backtrace:</p>
        <p style="margin-left:10px">
        File: /home/onlblcm/dev.mytranslator.com/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php<br />
        Line: 173<br />
        Function: _ci_load_library          </p>




        <p style="margin-left:10px">
        File: /home/onlblcm/dev.mytranslator.com/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php<br />
        Line: 192<br />
        Function: library           </p>


        <p style="margin-left:10px">
        File: /home/onlblcm/dev.mytranslator.com/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php<br />
        Line: 153<br />
        Function: libraries         </p>

        <p style="margin-left:10px">
        File: /home/onlblcm/dev.mytranslator.com/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php<br />
        Line: 65<br />
        Function: initialize            </p>


        <p style="margin-left:10px">
        File: /home/onlblcm/dev.mytranslator.com/application/modules/admin/controllers/Admin.php<br />
        Line: 8<br />
        Function: __construct           </p>
```

As you can see, it's going to: /home/onlblcm/dev.mytranslator.com/application/modules/admin/controllers/Admin.php

But that has no sense, since I am not calling my admin controller.

Again, if I call the command from SSH it's working, from CRON is messed up.

**EDIT 2:**
 I added to cron jobs this command:
    php -f /home/onlblcm/dev.blasteronline.com/index.php > az.txt 2>&1

I get the exact same thing (error) when calling from Cron Job.
 If I call it from SSH I get no output.
 if I call from cron, I get the error like above.

**EDIT 3:**
 I now managed to get the same error when using Putty/sssh.
 If I run the command (ssh) with
php ....
 It runs good
 If I run the command (ssh) with:
/usr/bin/php
 I get the same error like in cron.

With cron I tested with php ... and /usr/bin/php ... and I get the same error.

So somehow php is different than /usr/bin/php . 
 But I outputed the phpinfo and it's the same version.
 When I use php info (via ssh) and use php I get a 32KB file with information (not html formated). When I use /usr/bin/php calling a file with php info, I get a file with 94K info (it is html formatted).

What is happening? Any ideas?

**EDIT 3: SOLVED**
It seems somehow the cron was calling a different PHP (although same version).
From Putty (ssh) I did a "whereis php"
I found 2 folder: /usr/bin/php AND /usr/local/bin/php
It seems calling simple php or /usr/bin/php FAILED the cron
When calling the cron with /usr/local/bin/php IT WORKS

Thanks

Comment: clearly headers are being inserted. Let's see some code. Looks like you are sending a request somewhere?

Comment: but it works when calling from SSH (putty) with no problem! The controller simply needs to output "HELLO". There is no code actually.

Comment: try with /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/onlblcm/dev.mytranslator.com/index.php mytranslator cron cronTranslations > aaa.txt 2>&1

Comment: can we please see some code?

Comment: Found the issue, very strange, and maybe somebody can explain what the problem is. So when running php from SSH all went good. When running php from cron it failed. When running /usr/bin/php it failed again. But now I did a whereis php and I found /usr/local/bin/php . When I set the cron with /usr/local/bin/php IT WORKS!!!! Why is that? The php from /usr/bin/php is the same version as /usr/local/bin/php ...